# Visual Studio 2015 RC Cordova Tools - Plugin Fails to Launch

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-2015

After struggling for several hours with getting Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Tools set up and running, the first plugin I add, Device, fails to launch at onDeviceReady. No error is thrown. It simply does not launch and when I attempt to access one of its properties, then I get a JavaScript undefined exception.

Can anyone point me at a way to get at the cause of a plugin simply not working?

Comment: Which plugin are you struggling with.  There could be a number of reasons.

Comment: Do you get a white page or the page you are expecting?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, Device is the only plugin I've loaded as yet. It fails to launch.

Comment: The page loads as expected.

Comment: Maybe add a few alerts into the device  ( function onDeviceReady() {alert('bob');} before you start addressing the returned device object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the below is added on the top of your page:

```
<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

And Make sure the callbck events are added:

```
    <script>

    //Events
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    </script>
```

If it helps, the config file looks like this for the plugin in question:

```
   <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />
```

FYI - I have found the config designer useless - and have to edit the versions manually before deploying to the app stores (in this case for both win and android).  Using VS2013 - to scared of VS2015 RTM.   My config broke at some point while adding plugins, and now is half-baked, but working.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Out of the box, my 2013 Cordova Tools implementation worked like a charm. somewhere along the line, something got corrupted and it stopped working. After re-installs, uninstalls and more re-installs, not only did 2013 Cordova Tools completely fail, it even began to screw up things on my box that had nothing to do with Cordova.  So I decided to uninstall it and try the 2015 RC. It has been nightmarish getting it to work. Now that it works, it doesn't work that great, obviously, since the Device plugin won't even work. I'm seriously considering going back to command line.

Comment: I've been staring at my own code for too long. My 'console.log(device.cordova) ' was reporting the undefined error. problem was a misplaced closing curly brace. It was trying to access Device before onDeviceReady had actually fired. DUH. Thank you.

Comment: It is often the small things.  Showing my age, but cobol had a wonderful message saying "message near . (fullstop)", which did not help and was a nightmare to find.  Happy your is working.  VS is for me the best implementation / integration of Cordova, but it has very much still lacking and broken.